# How to access to external MySQL form AWS Glue

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, configuration, connection, aws-glue

I am trying to create an AWS Glue connection to an external MySQL database.

Do you know what is the right setup of security? About security groups, internet gateway, etc?

Actually I am getting this message:

> Check that your connection definition references your JDBC database with correct URL syntax, username, and password. Communications link failure

I have the database in my local environment and I tested accessing to my database from another location using MySQL Workbench with success.

Comment: Can do a simple test by launching an EC2 machine in the same VPC of that Glue connection and see if you are able to establish connection with on prem MySQL with same credentials

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help. Talked about the same thing but with a different database engine

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61945453/12950340